# What is the solution to avoid floating point precision issue in javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a problem when you perform an equation similar to this one:

```
let result = (num1/num2) - 1;
```

An example for that one is (157.23 / 120) -1, javascript gives a result of 31.024999999 but a regular calculator or calculator application give a result of **FIXED** 31.025

Is there any way how to avoid this issue?

Comment: use toFixed method of Javascript.              

Number( result.toFixed(2) );


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Comment: You can use result.toFixed(3), where 3 is number of values after decimal.